# c# winform Application how click webview2 next button?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, webview2

Below code not available any name or id for clicking. In there all class auto changing so not possible detect class as my knowledge.

can you help me how I am click next button?

please see html code below.

```
<div class="zQJV3" jsname="DH6Rkf" jscontroller="QEg9te" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;PIvFg:vjx2Ld(Njthtb),ChoyC(eBSUOb),VaKChb(gVmDzc),nCZam(W3Rzrc),Tzaumc(uRHG6),JGhSzd;dcnbp:dE26Sc(lqvTlf);FzgWvd:JGhSzd;"
  data-is-consent="false" data-is-primary-action-disabled="false" data-is-secondary-action-disabled="false" data-primary-action-label="Next"
  data-secondary-action-label="" jsshadow="">
    <div class="dG5hZc" jsname="DhK0U">
        <div class="qhFLie" jsname="k77Iif">
            <div jscontroller="Xq93uf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;" jsname="Njthtb" class="FliLIb DL0QTb">
                <div class="VfPpkd-dgl2Hf-ppHlrf-sM5MNb" data-is-touch-wrapper="true">
                    <button class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b"
                      jscontroller="soHxf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc; touchcancel:JMtRjd; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;"
                      data-idom-class="nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc qIypjc TrZEUc lw1w4b" jsname="LgbsSe" type="button">
                        <div class="VfPpkd-Jh9lGc"></div>
                        <div class="VfPpkd-RLmnJb"></div>
                        <span jsname="V67aGc" class="VfPpkd-vQzf8d">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="daaWTb" jsname="QkNstf">
            <div jscontroller="Xq93uf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;" jsname="gVmDzc" class="FliLIb n4P87">
                <div class="VfPpkd-dgl2Hf-ppHlrf-sM5MNb" data-is-touch-wrapper="true">
                    <button class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf ksBjEc lKxP2d uRo0Xe TrZEUc lw1w4b" jscontroller="soHxf" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc; touchcancel:JMtRjd; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;"
                      data-idom-class="ksBjEc lKxP2d uRo0Xe TrZEUc lw1w4b" jsname="LgbsSe" type="button">
                        <div class="VfPpkd-Jh9lGc"></div>
                        <div class="VfPpkd-RLmnJb"></div>
                        <span jsname="V67aGc" class="VfPpkd-vQzf8d">Back</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please see below for understand what I am need but it's not working.

```
webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('next').click();");
```

If you expert please help me for this.

Comment: Your `button` elements don't have an ìd` attribute, try this: `<button id="next"><button>` for the button you want to click.

Comment: Or if the HTML content isn't under your control you can do something like `Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('button')).filter(button => (button.textContent.trim() === 'Next'))[0].click()`. Also, its usually easier to try out your script in the browser before moving it over to WebView2. For example I used JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpxny2qw/